# interpolation across multiple columns with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d={'business':['FX','FX','FX','FX','IR','IR','IR','IR'],\
'A/L':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'],\
'date':(['01/01/2018','02/01/2018','03/01/2018','04/01/2018',\
'05/01/2018','06/01/2018','06/01/2019','06/01/2020']),\
'amt':[1,2,3,4,5,np.nan,7,8]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
df=df.groupby('business').apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
df
```

I want to interpolate the data above but want to include the date in the interpolation. So, rather than the current output of 6, I would have expected a number closer to 5 given the 1 year 'gap' between the two rows. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: set the date as index?

Comment: tried that ....does not work

Comment: You can try `df.set_index('date').groupby('business', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D').interpolate())` and extract only the dates in your original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the method to use to interpolate to `index` once you have set the 'date' column as index such as:

```
print (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby('business')
         .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method = 'index'))
         .reset_index())

        date business A/L       amt
0 2018-01-01       FX   A  1.000000
1 2018-01-02       FX   A  2.000000
2 2018-01-03       FX   A  3.000000
3 2018-01-04       FX   A  4.000000
4 2018-01-05       IR   A  5.000000
5 2018-01-06       IR   A  5.005464
6 2019-01-06       IR   A  7.000000
7 2020-01-06       IR   A  8.000000
```